# Why does $0 and all arguments disappear from running bash script as viewed by ps?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ps

I have a bash script (first line `#! /bin/bash`) called `do-doruns` that I invoke from the bash command line with `./do-doruns arg1 arg2 ...`

That script in turns calls the script `./dorun a1 a2 a3 ...`, and there are further levels of script and then a compiled program invoked.

When viewed with `ps`, `dorun` and all running things invoked under it appear in `ps` with their name and command line arguments, e.g.,

`/bin/bash /home/moss/path-to-dorun/dorun a1 a2 a3`

and so forth.  But no line for `do-doruns` shows up.  It's definitely running (waiting for child completion).  I can understand why its *arguments* might disappear (though separate testing has shown that using bash `shift` does not cause arguments to disappear when viewed from `ps`), but not its `$0` (command name).

While this is not a road block in my work, it's an odd mystery that I'd like to understand.  Versions of things are as follows:

- `uname -a` shows: `Linux moss-Ubuntu-SMCSim 5.4.0-81-generic #91-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 15 19:09:17 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- `bash --version` shows: `GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`
- `ps --version` shows (perhaps oddly): `ps from procps-ng UNKNOWN`

  This behavior is not restricted to `ps` - `top` shows it as well, so it seems more fundamental.
- Finally, if it matters, this is all running in a VirtualBox virtual machine.

  `vboxmanage --version` shows: `7.0.4r154605`

Comment: How do you know it's running? What's its pid? Or what's the parent pid of `dorun`? (`ps -o ppid -C dorun`). What's the output of `ps -fp that-pid`?

Comment: Also, how do you invoke `ps`? `ps -AfH | less` can help you show the ancestry of `dorun` better.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I obtained the pid as you suggested, and `ps -fp` on that pid gives:

`moss      245298  552161  0 Jun12 pts/8    00:00:00 /bin/bash`

I was using `ps auxwwww` to see the processes and looking through the results using `less`.  `ps -C do-doruns` returns nothing.  Always good to check, but I think I am seeing a real effect ...

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to change the command line of a shell using `exec` because the command after `exec` replaces the invoking shell.
Taking into account the comments about beautifying the printout of `/proc/pid/cmdline` here is version 2. But I don't see, how using eval to execute a command prepared in a variable would cause an implicit behaviour like `exec`.

Example v2:

```
#!/bin/bash

identifyMyself() {
echo "My cmdline: $0 My arg1: $1 My PID: $BASHPID"
echo "Kernel says:"
#cat -A /proc/$BASHPID/cmdline
#echo
readarray -d '' -t cmdline < /proc/$$/cmdline
#declare -p cmdline
printf '%s ' "${cmdline[@]}"
echo
}

identifyMyself "$1"

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
echo "calling myself with long parameters"
"$0" arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
fi

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
dorun="$0 arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4"
echo "calling myself with long parameters by evaling a variable"
eval "${dorun}"
fi

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
echo "I am still here"
identifyMyself "$1"
fi

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
echo "execing myself with long parameters"
exec "$0" arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
fi

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
echo "now I am gone"
identifyMyself "$1"
fi
```

Output:

```
$ ./bashtestv2_pid.sh
My cmdline: ./bashtestv2_pid.sh My arg1:  My PID: 1444428
Kernel says:
/bin/bash ./bashtestv2_pid.sh 
calling myself with long parameters
My cmdline: ./bashtestv2_pid.sh My arg1: arg1 My PID: 1444429
Kernel says:
/bin/bash ./bashtestv2_pid.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 
calling myself with long parameters by evaling a variable
My cmdline: ./bashtestv2_pid.sh My arg1: arg1 My PID: 1444430
Kernel says:
/bin/bash ./bashtestv2_pid.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 
I am still here
My cmdline: ./bashtestv2_pid.sh My arg1:  My PID: 1444428
Kernel says:
/bin/bash ./bashtestv2_pid.sh 
execing myself with long parameters
My cmdline: /home/user/bin/bashtestv2_pid.sh My arg1: arg1 My PID: 1444428
Kernel says:
/bin/bash /home/user/bin/bashtestv2_pid.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
```

Notice how the PID stays the same after exec while the command line changes. The `eval` behaves like the normal call. This is what you say in your comment. But in your own answer you state the opposite. Please give an example of an `eval` statement causing an implicit `exec`.

Comment: Well, there are no uses of `exec`.  One unusual thing I do is to use `eval`.  I build up the desired `dorun` command in a shell variable `cmd` and then do `eval $cmd`.  Experimentation with smaller scripts shows that such use of `eval`, on its own anyway, does not mess with the command line of the shell invoking `eval`.  Btw, confirmation that I am not using `exec` unintentionally lies in the fact that `do-doruns` does multiple invocations of `dorun` in a `for` loop, waiting for each to complete before starting the next one.  I appreciate your suggestions; yet I remain mystified.

Comment: FYI, you can avoid the ugliness of `cat -A` by reading /proc/pid/cmdline into an array - e.g. `readarray -d '' -t cmdline < /proc/$$/cmdline`. You can then print the array with, e.g., `declare -p cmdline` or `printf '%s ' "${cmdline[@]}" ; echo`.   BTW, in bash, `mapfile` is a synonym for `readarray` and you can get details about it by running `help mapfile` (`help readarray` doesn't say much more than "A synonym for 'mapfile'")

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on what the first line of your script looks like as this changes the command name which is used by the `ps -C` option and possibly how you match it with grep (depending on what flags you are using).

Using something like

```
#!/bin/bash
```

will change the command name to the name of the script, so this would show up as do-dorun.

Using

```
#!/bin/env bash
```

will mean the command name will remain as bash.

The command line will look the same for both, e.g. `/bin/bash myscriptname.sh arg1 arg2 arg3`

Answer (score 0):

Further research, namely reducing my scripts to a minimal test case, suggest that this behavior results from use of bash's `eval` builtin.  The minimal test case is:

```
#! /bin/bash
eval foo xyz
```

where `foo` is some other script to run.  (This probably happens with programs as well, though I did not specifically test it.)

What seems to happens is the `eval` causes the shell to fork-exec a `bash` using the `-c` command line option to give the command line to run.  It appears that such an invocation of bash results in a job whose command line appears empty, I suppose because the command line has been read and the bash then just exec's to the desired program.

So, if I don't want that behavior, it seems I should avoid using `eval`.

Thanks for helping me think it through!